# language SEO optimization of URL's in MVC 3/4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, asp.net-mvc-4, seo

I'm doing an website which has multiple languages like **Danish, English and German.**

But what is the correct way to format the url for the different languages.

Is it like so:

> English = http://www.mysite.dk/myController/Hepper  **(Without an /en/ in
>   the url)**
>
> or
>
> English = http://www.mysite.dk/en/myController/Hepper **(with the /en/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the language in the URL is best in terms of SEO. Of course if there's a default language you might omit it. For example:

- `http://www.mysite.dk/myController/Hepper` (English)
- `http://www.mysite.dk/fr/myController/Hepper` (French)
- `http://www.mysite.dk/de/myController/Hepper` (German)
- ...